# Get data from the parent scope

Tags: ractivejs

Im trying to implement a single-page app with Ractive using components, and I need to have some page-wide options. I did like this:

```
...
data: {
    options: {
        someOption: true
    },
...
```

Everything was fine while I used it like `{{#if options.someOption}}`, but then I faced a problem - `rective.get('options.someOption')` returns undefined (both with `ractive.get('options')`). Observing dont work as well. Is there any way to make my code understand me?

UPD. Accidentally solved problem with a portion of magic - get() starts working when I place {{options.someOption}} on template.

Comment: I think this is a bug! I've raised an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1228. Thanks

Comment: Hey @Xandrmoro, just FYI that issue has been fixed now: http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/c0kvgc1s/ It'll be part of the next stable release, or you can use the edge build straight away (http://cdn.ractivejs.org/edge/ractive.js)

Comment: @RichHarris, ty! Developers responsiveness is, maybe, the biggest cons of Ractive :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ractive programmatic data access within an instance (includes components) can currently only "see" data that is:

1. Defined as data
2. Specified explicitly as a component parameter
3. Used as a reference in the template

For #1, you can include the options as default data and it will be available to all instances:

```
Ractive.default.data = {
    options: {...}
}
```

Any new Ractive instance, including components, will have an `options` data property.

For #2, even if you have deeply nested components, you can have the parent of the component that needs the data include it as a parameter:

```
// Component somewhere in the "app" hierarchy.
// By referencing {{options}} in its template, it will find that data
// make it explicit on the widget component, which can then use it
// programmatically

<widget options='{{options}}'/>
```

For #3, you can include a "dummy" reference in the component template:

```
// by using it in the template, it is now available for programatic access
{{#with options}}{{/with}}
```

Of course then there's #4, enhancing Ractive to allow same lookup in code as template

Comment: Options #4 now works for `ractive.get()` in components for parent data ([still need set](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1284)).